# http request is frozen on iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have an app developed with Xamarin Forms for Android, iOS and Windows UWP. The last week I build a new version in order to fix some errors and I test it… and Works perfectly. I send to certificate and it pass the Apple test for certification.. but this week the app doesn’t work!
I’m checking and I can see as app request http to server and this answer but app is frozen up to closed it by OS. On debug mode, app is frozen forever on:

`await httpclient.post(....)`

What happen?  The object httpclient never finish although server answer it in less 100ms.
I have tried to navigate on the repository to the before reléase (on july) and I have build the code and it doesn’t work…. What happen with the last SDK iOS 14? What should I do in order to work?
My project use MvvM and has updated to last SDK of Xamarin, MS Appcenter,...

I have tested with xamarin forms up to 4.6 and works correctly. It is frozen on request http with Xamarin form 4.7 and 4.8.

Comment: Did  you add the attributes for http request on the info.plist file ?

Comment: The api rest is HTTPS, I'm using ngrok service... and the project is using NSUrl in order to support 1.2 TLS. Other times, when SSL isn't accepted by iOS, version SSL, etc... it fire an exception but in this case... nothing. is frozen. Anyway I will try it in order to check if it is the problem. Thank you

Comment: Try to wrap the post call in a try/catch method a run it outside the main thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All problems are from an Entry with IsPassword=True. This entry fire problems on http request, later on Navigation.... and finally I can find the root of problem. It.
Thank every body

Comment: Don't forget to accept your answer , which will help more people who has similar issue .